# Want to split a text file into one file per line

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, split

I have a text file that is generated daily that has between 20 and 50 lines, each ending with a set delimiter, currently ~ but that can be changed to anything. I want to take this text file and split it into 20 to 50 different files, with one line per file. Ideally I'd like to do this from a windows batch file, or at least a program that I can script to run daily. Appreciate any help you can provide, thanks!

Sample Input File:

```
GS*SH*CSMZ9*20131209*0908*000000001*X*004010|ST*856*0001|BSN*00*000000001~
GS*SH*CSMZ9*20131209*0912*003400004*X*004010|SG*834*0001|TSN*00*000000004~
GS*SH*CSMZ5*20131209*1001*000040007*X*004010|ST*855*0001|BSN*00*000000007~
GS*SH*CSMZ9*20131209*1019*000000010*X*004010|SG*856*0001|BGN*00*000000010~
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /n "^" "file.txt"') do for /f "delims=~" %%c in ("%%~b") do >"text%%a.txt" echo(%%c
```

Comment: I am trying this on the file and the output I am getting is Chinese characters. A sample like of my file would be something like: 100* 548477* 44399947566* 93948575647~ then new line and the next line would be in that same format. Any idea why this isn't working? Thanks!

Comment: Added a sample input file. Thanks!

Comment: @tsHunter tested it with your data, works fine. [session screenshot](http://img34.imageshack.us/img34/725/qcj7.png)

Comment: Interesting. It looks like it failed to work cause my file was being created in unicode for some reason. When I copied the data to a clean txt file it worked fine. I'll have to fix the format of the file. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I propose python here.  Much more readable that any shell script.

```
f=open("filename")
lines = f.read().split('~')
for (n, line)  in enumerate(lines):
    open( "newname{}".format(n), "w" ).write(line)
```

Comment: `Python` is not part of the Windows distro.

Comment: It is part of any Windows around here :-)

Comment: I'd like to try to avoid python if I can but its good to know its an option if needed, thanks

Comment: exactly what I needed to split a 2.5M values on 83 lines insert into 83 separate files to avoid mysql command timeout on shared server :-)

Answer (score 0):

This should create files called `00000001.txt` and increment the number for each line.

If any line contains `!` then it needs an extra modification.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set c=0
for /f "delims=" %%a in (file.txt) do (
   set /a c+=1
   set name=0000000!c!
   set name=!name:~-8!.txt
   >!name! echo %%a
)
```

Comment: Hmmm can't seem to get this to work. Fails to create any files. Thanks though

Comment: I tested it and it works.  Did you name your text file to `file.txt`?

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "destdir=c:\destdir"
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a IN ('findstr /n "." q21239387.txt') DO (
 >"%destdir%\filename%%a.txt" ECHO(%%b
)

GOTO :EOF
```

where `q21239387.txt` is the name of the file I used as input for testing.

Files `filename1.txt`..`filename99.txt` created in the destination directory (99 is # lines in the file)

Note - will not correctly output source lines that begin with  <kbd>:</kbd> if that is a problem.